# Перевод в модуле Yii2

Tags: yii2, i18n

Не могу настроить перевод для модуля сайта на Yii2

Конфиг @app\config\main.php

```php
    'components' => [
        'i18n' => [
            'translations' => [
                '*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => 'haise\messages',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'app'           => 'app.php',
                        'sendmail-form' => 'sendmail-form.php',
                    ]
                ],
                'modules/trade/*' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                    'basePath' => 'haise\modules\trade\messages',
                    'fileMap' => [
                        'trade' => 'trade.php',
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ],
```

Использование во вью моего модуля @app\modules\trade\views\nav.php

```php
    <li><a href="/users/"><?= Yii::t('trade', 'Profile'); ?></a></li>
```

Что я делаю не так и как оно должно быть по "правилам хорошего кода"?

Answer (score 0):

Логично, что перевод модуля должен лежать в модуле. Но также логично, что он и подключаться должен в модуле. Для этого в файле `Module.php` в методе `init()` можно добавить такой код.

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->moduleName = self::MODULE_NAME;
    if (!isset(\Yii::$app->i18n->translations[$this->moduleName . '*'])) {
        \Yii::$app->i18n->translations[$this->moduleName . '*'] = [
            'class' => PhpMessageSource::class,
            'sourceLanguage' => 'ru',
            'basePath' => __DIR__ . '/messages',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил этот фрагмент кода:
1. Фреймворку не понравилась константа MODULE_NAME - переделал на \Yii::$app->controller->module
2. Из конфига убрал фрагмент, отвечающий за перевод.

Итог: Ничего. Никаких изменений не происходит. Ни ошибок, но перевода =(
В какую сторону копать?

Comment: А файл перевода есть и назван правильно?